# How can I UN-orphan media files?

Tags: database

Something wrecked a non-profit WordPress site I'm responsible for (I'm not a WP expert, just the most technical of all our volunteers).  I was able to restore most of it from a backup, but the database seems to have forgotten most of the links to the media in the wp-content/uploads.  All the media is still in the directories, but the database doesn't know it is there.

Obviously I could manually re-import all the hundreds of photos, but before I resort to that, I wanted to see if there is a technique or a plugin that would add everything already neatly sorted and stored in /uploads to the media database.  Most of the plugins I've found are all about deleting orphans, but I need to add them to the db.

Comment: Re-importing them wouldn't be that different from what you're asking, either way posts of type `attachment` would need to be created and filled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is random, but a friend of mine got himself into the same situation a two weeks back and found this plugin to be helpful.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/media-sync/

But as Tom mentioned above in his comment, you'll run into attachment post type issues.

Hope this helps you get half way there!!

Comment: That was exactly what I needed - it got me 100% of the way there!  Many thanks!

Comment: Another, more complex option seems to be the [Bulk Media Register](https://wordpress.org/plugins/bulk-media-register/) plugin.